# Synonym discussion: [teamspeak], [ventrilo] -> [voice-chat]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As part of the clean up do we want to be grouping up [ventrilo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ventrilo) and [teamspeak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamspeak) and any similar tags under [voice-chat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-chat) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd argue against it. While there are one or two questions under either tag which might be helpful to users of a different voice chat platform, for the most part, these questions seem to be pretty darned specific to one specific piece of software. There's no compelling reason to combine the tags that I can see.